# Editing a Date field in Appengine Data Store Viewer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datetime, date, google-cloud-datastore

Does anyone know how edit a field with type 'Date' in the appengine data store viewer in production? It seems like it maps to an int field and I tried putting in the number of milliseconds since epoch but that didnt work.

Comment: I tried this out, and I'm getting different results. The production datastore viewer shows my date field as a type of "gd:when" and a value of "2010-07-08 00:00:00". The docs also indicate that DateProperty is internally converted to datetime.datetime.

Comment: Are you using java or python?

Answer (score 1):

If a value is existing and you try to change it (like in your case), it shouldn't be a problem. The Date is internally stored as Python datetime.datetime object

Comment: what if the field doesn't have a value yet?

Comment: There is not solution for this, at the moment. It has to be done programatically. What i do, is to use remote api shell and change the value i want. Its kinda convenient and fast